# Fujikawa method for arbitrary transformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, chirality, quantum-anomalies

When the [Fujikawa method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawa_method) is presented in every book I've read so far, the transformation is initially written as $e^{i\chi (x) \gamma^{5}}$. The trace of $i\chi(x)\gamma^{5}$ is done by including a regularizing factor of some sort, and using the eigenfunctions of the relevant operator in the Lagragian. What I don't get is why so many texts ultimately set $\chi(x)=\delta^{(4)}(x)$. It's obviously easier to deal with, but what about more complicated transformations?

Comment: I removed the second question about resources for functional Jacobians, but I think it should be fine to post it separately. Make sure to use the [tag:resource-recommendations] tag. Also if you want to do us a favor, you could flag it for moderator attention once you post it, so we can apply the post notice for resource recommendations (it just says that we want detailed answers).

Comment: Will do, sorry about that.

Comment: I have not read "many texts" about the Fujikawa method, but the method I know does not set $\chi(x) = \delta^4(x)$. Could you provide references that do that, and ask a more specific question? (*"what about more complicated transformations?"* has the obvious, and correct answer: "Well, you don't set $\chi(x)$ to be the Dirac delta, then.")

Comment: I'm currently using Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians by R. Ticciati, but I've seen his derivation elsewhere. It's in Weinberg as well. I guess I should have asked what happens when $\chi (x)\neq \delta^{(4)}(x)$